# How to efficiently track the total number of lines of code in my Ruby on Rails project on Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ide, browser-plugin, browser-addons

*IDE - Cloud9 - Metrics*

**How do I efficiently track the total number of lines of code in my project?**

I assume I need a plugin

It is a rails app, perhaps there is a gem available?

Does chrome provider an inspector tool and/or plugin to accommodate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

```
bundle exec rake stats
```